# Excel VBA to read MS Word comments unique ID

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm writing an Excel macro to read MS Word comments and put it in a sheet. To do this I'm using this VBA Functions:

```
        Set myWord = New Word.Application
        Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(varFile)

        For Each thisComment In myDoc.Comments

            With thisComment
                destSheet.Cells(rowToUse, colToUse + 2).Value = .Range.Text
                destSheet.Cells(rowToUse, colToUse + 5).Value = .Scope.Text
            End With
            rowToUse = rowToUse + 1
        Next thisComment
```

Is there a VBA function that could give me the internal number of the comment? I cannot use INDEX because it gave me the location of the comment inside the collection, and it change if the user insert another comments.

What I need is to be able to identify the comments inside the sheet, so I can Append/Update/Delete comments (specially Update) on the sheet.

I'm using MS Word comments to insert "qualitative coding" info on my documents, controling with added specific info (for each comment) in a Excel sheet.

Warm regards

Comment: Withou knowing about Word, I'd say, fill a dictionary with the comments already on your sheet. Then check if the "new" comment exists and if so, one code, if not, add it to your sheet.

Comment: What do you mean with "internal number of the comment"? `Index` would be the only property that actually does return a `Long` that represents the position of an item in a collection. Otherwise you'll have to go through other properties like `Date`. And sort them accordingly in memory, which would give you a collection of comments from old to newest.

Comment: The problem of this approach @Damian is taht if the user change a comment (inside Word) I'll not ble able to find the old version of it no the sheet to Update it. So I nned something that could link them even if they change. Of course, if a comment are deleted or inserted in word I can delete or create it on the sheet, but not "update".

Comment: Hi @JvdV the is that, as you'd said, Index "return a Long that represents the position of an item in a collection" and the date could give me comments sorted from oldest to newest. But What I need is some kind of "reference" that is unique for a comment, and stands even if the user change its content, so I could link Word and Excel comments to know when I need to "Update" a comment.

Comment: No matter if a user changes a comment, `Date` property will keep returning the original date/timevalue when the comment was added originally. I think this is the most "unique" property as you can get from a comment imo.

Comment: Hi @JvdV I'm afraid that time stamps of a comment change. Please, take a look here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/c90e56d7-8f76-4c05-933f-c214de92f3fe/displaying-timestamps-on-comment-balloons

Comment: Then I'm out of guesses as to which property you could potentially utilize, sorry

Comment: Word has nothing that can identify a comment. Could you please clarify more verbosely what the requirement is? This isn't telling me that: "I'm using MS Word comments to insert "qualitative coding" info on my documents, controling with added specific info (for each comment) in a Excel sheet."